# How to change pictures using listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to find out for hours how I can use a menu to select a picture, for example if the list had a carrot in it; there would be a picture of a carrot beside it when you click it. I am not very experienced with visual basic (I just started) so I need your guys help. I have some code already but I don't think it works

```
 Dim imgList As New ImageList
  ListView1.View = View.Details
  ListView1.Width = 500
  ListView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
  ListView1.AllowColumnReorder = True
  ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = 1
  ImageList1.Images.Add("Name", Image.FromFile("C:\pic\test.jpeg"))
  ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ListViewItem.ImageIndex` to the Index of the image in the `ImageList`, when adding a new `ListViewItem` it`s as simple as:

```
ImageList1.Images.Add("Key", Image.FromFile("C:\pic\test.jpeg"))
Dim newItem = New ListViewItem("Item Name", ImageList1.Images.IndexOfKey("Key"))
ListView1.Items.Add(newItm)
```

When dealing with already added items you can set it directly, by refrence, index or what have you:

```
'set ListViewItem.ImageIndex for ListViewItem at index 0
'using ListViewItem.Tag can be usefull for this
ListView1.Items(0).Tag = New String("Key")
ListView1.Items(0).ImageIndex = ImageList1.Images.IndexOfKey(ListView1.Items(0).Tag.ToString)
```

Comment: Ok I kinda got it to work but when I click on test name,it spams the box with testname I provided a screen shot below     http://prntscr.com/1ne67e  @raphael smit , here is the code I currently have http://pastebin.com/f19usyv7

Comment: also since im new at this what do you mean by New String("Key").

Comment: i gave you two options of setting the image for it, either directly(2nd method) or when you add the item for the first time(1st method), combining them is not such a good idea, also i presume you have added it to a event ? which is part of the reason why its duplicating most likely. You probably want to use the 2nd method, as for New String("Key") that sets the item tag to a new string with a certain key which you can use to identify/find the matching imagelist index.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have just one more question could you give me an example for New String("Key"), We all got to start somewhere, and you're great help!!!.

Comment: Basically because the `ListViewItem.Tag` property is a object you can set it to anything that inherits object(it is a very basic type and a lot of things inherit it), the part `New String("")` assigns a string to it, its basically there to store some information with the `ListViewItem` that can be used use when working with it.